# Replacing the words in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I just want to swap the words in a string, consider:

```
var str = "this is a test string";
```

now test should be replaced by string & string should be replaced by test
so that output should be

```
"this is a string test"
```

Actual code:

```
<html>
<title> Swappping Words </title>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var o_name = prompt("Enter the String", "");
        var replace1 = prompt("Enter the first word to replace ", "");
        var r1 = prompt("replacing word of 1", "")
        var replace2 = prompt("Enter the second word to replace ", "");
        var r2 = prompt("replacing word of 2", "")
        var n_name1 = o_name.replace(replace1, r1).replace(replace2, r2);
        document.writeln("Old string = " +o_name);
        document.writeln("New string = " +n_name1);
    </script>  
</body>
```

I'm learning the basics, can someone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: If you are looking to just switch the words there is a specific example for that.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace

Comment: [Go learn RegExp you won't regret it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: try this: `str = "this is a string test";`... now, if you want something more useful then detail your rules: Will it always be them two words? Do you have a set of example inputs/outputs where the original content is different?

Answer (score 9):

The main problem you will face is that unless you do both replacements at once, you will risk overwriting your first replacement with the second.

Try this:

```
var result = str.replace(/test|string/g,function(m) {
    switch(m) {
        case "test": return "string";
        case "string": return "test";
    }
});
```

Comment: Sub in `new RegExp(replace1+"|"+replace2,"g")` insted of the regex literal, and replace the hardcoded strings with the corresponding variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use temporary placeholders so you don't overwrite while swapping values. In so many lines, just so you get the idea clearly.

```
<script>
var s="this is a test string";
s=s.replace("string","#temp#");
s=s.replace("test","string");
s=s.replace("#temp#","test");
alert(s);
</script>
```